# How can I interact with an element behind a Flatlist?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Sorry if this has been asked previously, but I hadn't found a working answer.

I'm currently working on a simple app. The main screen features a vertical flatlist with user generated content. The header, though, is transparent and has a predefined height, so the user can see a background image; when the flatlist is scrolled, it covers this background image, which remains static. The goal is to give the user the feeling that they're covering this image, similar to the pull-up element on google maps, which covers the map to show more data.

This would be a simplified example of the current, working code, so you get the gist of it:

```
const HomeComponent = () => ( 
    <View>
        <ImageBackground source={require('../assets/background.png')}>
            <Flatlist
             headerComponent={<TransparentHeaderOfPredefinedHeight/>}
             data={DATA}
             renderItem={renderItem}
             keyExtractor={item => item}/>
        </ImageBackground>
    </View>  )
```

Up until here, everything is fine. The thing is, I would like to add a touchable button on this background, that is subsequently covered when the Flatlist is scrolled.

Here's the issue. I have no way to make the touch event propagate through the flatlist's header and reach this button. I tried using pointerEvents='none' and 'box-only' in different combinations, but whenever I was able to touch that button, I was in turn unable to scroll or to interact with the flatlist elements.

I also tried pushing the background image and button on the flatlist header, and using the vertical offsite of the flatlist scrolling to move these elements and simulate the flatlist scrolling over it. Unfortunately, the result was absolutely atrocious, lacking any kind of smoothness.

Does anyone know how I could implement this functionality? I can provide more info if needed. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hello, why not do a collapsing header so that you can have access even if your flatlets is scrolled or when it is not. And it has a cool effect if you know how to manage your animation (cf: https://itnext.io/react-native-collapsible-headers-explained-78584ff133d8). You can put your header then your flatlist (not embedded in the header). Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the input! This would be a great alternative, but unfortunately, this is not the behaviour my client requested, so I'm still stuck with a flatlist. Thank you for your input however, and I'll discuss it with him to see if he's ok with a collapsing header instead.